# Trouble proving that the boundaries do not matter when finding the area under the curve of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was writing a note to myself about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but then I stumbled on the final hurdle. While I could prove that $A(x)$ tells you the area under the curve between $x=0$ and $x=x$, I could not generalise this proof to show that the *definite integral* between $x=a$ and $x=b$ tells you the area under any curve, no matter what the boundaries are.

In other words, I could prove that:
$$A(x) = \int f(x)dx$$
But not:
$$\text{Area}=\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

Here is what I had written:

> The fundamental theorem of calculus links the concepts of derivatives
>   and integrals together. While at first glance, finding the area under
>   a curve seems unrelated to finding a gradient function, these
>   represent 'opposite' operations. In other words, when we differentiate
>   $f(x)$ to find $f'(x)$, we are computing the gradient function of
>   $f(x)$; and when we integrate $f'(x)$, we can use $f(x)$ to find the
>   area under the curve of $f'(x)$. Just as differentiation and
>   integration are inverse operations, so too are finding the gradient
>   function and finding the area under the curve.
>
> The geometric interpretation of this theorem and its proof are as
>   follows: [image]
>
> $$ y=f(x)\\ \text{let $A(x)=$ the area under the curve between $x=0$
>   and $x=x$}\\ $$
>
> The area between $A(x)$ and $A(x+h)$, where $h$ is a small number, is
>   equal to $A(x+h)-A(x)$
>
> $A(x+h)-A(x)$ is approximately equal to rectangle. This approximation
>   ignores changes in the height of the curve, but as $h$ tends towards
>   $0$, the error caused by this approximation also tends towards $0$.
>   Therefore, we can say that:
>
> $$ A(x+h)-A(x)\approx \text{base $\times$ height} = hf(x) $$
>
> Dividing both sides by h gives:
>   $$ f(x) \approx \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h} \\
> f(x) = \lim_\limits{h \to 0} \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h} $$
>
> We also know the following is true from the First Principle of
>   Differentiation:
>
> $$ A'(x)= \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h} $$
>
> Consequently,
>
> $$ A'(x) = f(x) $$
>
> And integrating both sides gives us our final answer:
>
> $$ A(x) = \int f(x)dx $$

Comment: OK, so what is $A(b)-A(a)$?

Comment: @Vasya $A(b) - A(a)$ is the area under the curve between $x=a$ and $x=b$! This can be represented as a definite integral because $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ means "integrate the function and find A(b) - A(a)". Thank you.

Comment: In other words, I could write: $\text{area under the curve between $x=a$ and $x=b$ } = A(b) - A(a) = \int f(b)dx - \int f(a)dx= \int_a^b f(x)dx$

Answer (score 1):

I usually "prove" this - admittedly with a bit of hand-waving - as follows: we write the theorem in the form $$\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx = f(b) - f(a)$$ and choose some segmentation of $a=a_0 < a_1 < ... < a_n = b$ of the interval $[a,b]$. Then the integral can be written (without limits) as the Riemann sum $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f'(x_i)(x_{i+1} - x_i) $$ According to the definition of the derivative we might write $$f'(x_i)\approx\frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}.$$ Replacing $f'$ within the Riemann sum of the integral, we just get a telescoping sum, and the result follows. This reasoning is not completely rigorous, but might possibly be helpful anyways.